# python matplotlib edit histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, decimal, bins

I used matplotlib to create a histogram. There are still problems I couldn't solve on my own or with the help of the internet.

1. How can I change the color of certain bins? In detail I want to change the color of bins with: a.) value  bin < 1.15 red, b.) value 1.15 < bin < 1.25 
   c.) value > 1.25 red?
2. How can I label the X-Axis not only with numbers with 1 decimal but also with 2 decimals (right now simply not plotted)?

   ```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   import numpy as np
   import csv

   thickness = []  #gets thickness from list
   bins = [1.00,1.01,1.02,1.03,1.04,1.05,1.06,1.07,1.08,1.09,1.10,1.11,1.12,1.13,1.14,1.15,1.16,1.17,1.18,1.19,1.20,1.21,1.22,1.23,1.24,1.25,1.26,1.27,1.28,1.29,1.30,1.31,1.32,1.33,1.34,1.35,1.36,1.37,1.38,1.39,1.40,1.41,1.42,1.43,1.44,1.45,1.46,1.47,1.48,1.49,1.50
   ] #set bins manuelly

   with open('control.txt','r') as csvfile:
   plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
   for row in plots:
       #x.append(float(row[0]))
       thickness.append(float(row[1]))

   plt.hist(thickness, bins, align='left', histtype='bar', rwidth=0.8, color='green')

   plt.xlabel('thickness [mm]')
   plt.ylabel('frequency')
   plt.title('Histogram')
   plt.show()
   ```

**See the plotted histogram below:**

[plt.histogram so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dp67.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (there may be some bugs):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import csv
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter


thickness = []  #gets thickness from list
bins = [1.00,1.01,1.02,1.03,1.04,1.05,1.06,1.07,1.08,1.09,1.10,1.11,1.12,1.13,1.14,1.15,1.16,1.17,1.18,1.19,1.20,1.21,1.22,1.23,1.24,1.25,1.26,1.27,1.28,1.29,1.30,1.31,1.32,1.33,1.34,1.35,1.36,1.37,1.38,1.39,1.40,1.41,1.42,1.43,1.44,1.45,1.46,1.47,1.48,1.49,1.50
] #set bins manuelly

with open('control.txt','r') as csvfile:
plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
for row in plots:
    #x.append(float(row[0]))
    thickness.append(float(row[1]))

h,bins = plt.hist(thickness, bins)
plt.clf()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(bins[bins<1.2],h[bins<1.2],rwidth=0.8, color='red')
plt.bar(bins[np.logical_and(bins>1.2,bins<1.5)],h[np.logical_and(bins>1.2,bins<1.5)],rwidth=0.8, color='green')
ax.bar(bins[bins>1.5],h[bins>1.5],rwidth=0.8, color='red')

ax.set_xlabel('thickness [mm]')

ax.set_ylabel('frequency')
ax.set_title('Histogram')

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))  
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick help. I tried to use your code now. I am new to programming and I only can asume what you did here. I get and error:"    h,bins = plt.hist(thickness, bins)ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)". Can you help me fix this bug?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the function returns more than two fields. Sorry about that. This should work: `h,bins,rest = plt.hist(thickness, bins)`. The code records the bins and heights of the bars, then clean the image (plt.clf()), then plot the bars.